# How can I access the matched of a regular expression in \regex_extract_once?

Tags: latex3, l3regex, regular-expressions

This time I have a function that takes strings and shall test whether the color given after the last dash is in a given set of colors or not. While I am able to design a regular expression for it, it seems I am too stupid to access the results, that I expected to be stored in `l_IconAndColor_seq`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ColorNameChopper}{m}
{
    \my_colornamechopper:n { #1 }
}

\seq_new:N \l_IconAndColor_seq

\cs_new:Nn \my_colornamechopper:n
{
    #1: & \regex_extract_once:nnNTF 
    {\A(.*)-(Black|White)\Z}
     {#1}
     \l_IconAndColor_seq
     {TRUE & \seq_item:Nn \l_IconAndColor_seq {2} & \seq_item:Nn 
     \l_IconAndColor_seq {3} & 
     \seq_count:N \l_IconAndColor_seq}
     {FALSE}\\
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
    String & Found & First & Second & Size\\
    \ColorNameChopper{Test-Black}
    \ColorNameChopper{Test-White}
    \ColorNameChopper{Test-Orange}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I am probably struggling of something simple, but I can't see it and so long the sequence is empty:

[image]

Comment: please follow the guide line for expl3 names. Use `\l_tobibs_IconAndColor_seq` and `\tobibs_colornamechopper:n`.

Comment: Little nitpick: according to the rule spelled out in [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) (§8.1.2, *Characters in regular expressions*), the dash should be matched with `\-` in the regular expression: “non-alphanumeric printable ASCII characters can (and should) always be escaped:
many of them have special meaning (e.g., use `\(`, `\)`, `\?`, `\.`, `\^`)”.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for pointing that out, I am still not used to the overall syntax of LaTeX3 and should probably once read through the whole "The LATEX3 Interfaces" guide. Shame on me.

Comment: @frougon thanks for pointing that out, it is a pity that there are so many dialects of RegExps out there, but i will improve my LaTeX3 RegExp skills.

Comment: @TobiBS Regarding the naming conventions that Ulrike pointed out, you only need to read [expl3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf) which is 16 pages long, including bibliography and index. :-) interface3.pdf is a reference manual, I'd say “no one” reads it all in one go.

Comment: @frougon That sounds more like something I can digest. Thanks for the reading tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the sequence in a table cell and try to use it in another one.

Besides, you want to use the *last* item in the sequence.

The first problem can be solved by expanding the contents prior to using it. The other one is solved by using item –1

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ColorNameChopper}{m}
  {
    \tobibs_colornamechopper:n { #1 }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__tobibs_colornamechopper_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tobibs_colornamechopper:n
  {
    #1: &
     \regex_extract_once:nnNTF {(.*)-(Black|White)} {#1} \l__tobibs_colornamechopper_seq
       {
         \use:e
           {
             TRUE &
             \seq_item:Nn \l__tobibs_colornamechopper_seq {-2} &
             \seq_item:Nn \l__tobibs_colornamechopper_seq {-1} &
             \seq_count:N \l__tobibs_colornamechopper_seq
           }
       }
       {FALSE}
    \\
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lllll}
String & Found & First & Second & Size\\
\ColorNameChopper{Test-Black}
\ColorNameChopper{Test-White}
\ColorNameChopper{Test-Orange}
\ColorNameChopper{Test-again-Black}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How and why does it work? First of all, your command `\regex_extract_once:nnNTF` sets the sequence in a table cell, so as soon as TeX processes `&` (when typesetting), the value would be lost.

However, if we build the whole table row before processing it, the value would not be lost (expansion takes place at a different level than typesetting, so TeX will not “see” the `&`, as it's just expanding macros and still not building the table. Yes, tables are quite hard to manage.

Comment: I believe the idea behind “First” and “Second” is, for the OP, to show the contents of the two capturing groups (items 2 and 3 of `\l__tobibs_colornamechopper_seq`). Also, maybe you could say that `\use:e` does the intended job here because `\seq_item:Nn` and `\seq_count:N` are expandable.

Comment: @frougon Perhaps. But look at the original code…

Comment: I did: I was preparing an answer but you posted before I finished. :-) I'm saying this because I think the “expandable” condition is not obvious for the OP. Anyway, it is now spelled out here.

Comment: @egreg so the sequence loses its value outside of the table cell, because that is out of it's scope? How does that happen? I thought as I defined it with `seq_new` it will persist until it is overwritten by the next `\regex_extract_once:nnNTF` call. Or do I get the order of expansion wrong and things happen in a different order then I am anticipating?

Comment: @frougon you are actually right and I corrected my mistake in the question. What I want is the name `Test` and the color `Black` to be separated by the RegExp. Honestly I don't get the hint with the `\use:e`, can you elaborate a bit more on that? The manual says it works like `\expand`, but how does that help here? In general expansion is my nightmare topic for LaTeX programming. ;-)

Comment: @TobiBS Table cells form groups.

Comment: @egreg good to know, thank you!

Comment: @TobiBS I fixed the code so the first part is also shown; I also added some comments.

Comment: @TobiBS This would be way too long for a comment, but the “annex” [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2007#a2255) should put you on track. Expandable macros are marked with a star in [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf).

Comment: @frougon Alone this annex looks frightening to me, but I will give it a try. ;-) I already got stuck in the next expansion problem, as i try to colorize the text now. But before opening a new question, I try to fix it myself by reading through the material you linked here.

Comment: @TobiBS If you are with the TeXbook, you're not alone. :)